# How do I find influenced program,when i add a column.Oracle & C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a question.

I need the table A add a column, its name is called "A1" then happed a program of company is not working,because it programs use Merge into method, let this program not run, until I add "A1" and Related code write into this Program.

This Program is C# Program.

Now, I will add a new column in the table B.
But my company has many program access in table B, and I don't know how many program access the table B...

So, how to do that, let me can advance find influenced program?

or

How to know which C# programs are using oracle  operating table b ,
let me can get these programe name & path

Thinks!

Comment: You can look at the `v$session` table, the `Module` column will give you names of external applications that are connecting.

Comment: This is very good method !!!!
but...i was used this method ,i discovered Module name was same...

I think, cause it by  the former employee of company does..

so , i need new  method ...

Comment: and this same module name is not the same program, it's just name same...

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to communicate, sorry. Your question is very unclear. I can't understand the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @WSC - v$session will only show what is _currently_ connected.

Comment: Yes. Connecting is the verb, connected is the adjective. E.g. "I am currently connecting to this database" and "I am currently connected to this database". I guess it is good to clarify though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your code is inside the database itself (as stored procedures) there is nothing in oracle that can tell you. And since you said your code is in C#, that appears to be the case. This is where you have to rely an a search with whatever facilities are available in your source code control system.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by program here. But If you want to know which all PL/SQL objects are using `TABLE_A` then you can use the `USER_DEPENDENCIES` view as follows:

```
SELECT REFERENCED_OWNER,
       NAME,
       TYPE
  FROM USER_DEPENDENCIES
 WHERE REFERENCED_OWNER = 'SCHEMA_NAME_OF_TABLE_A'
   AND REFERENCED_NAME = 'TABLE_A';
```

Comment: Thank you for your question, I have added it.